MDAC AC reference input
I previously had a question on using AC reference voltage with a MDAC, But it has been addressed nicely in the answer below.
How does the "Multiplying Bandwidth" specification relate to a DAC output's maximum bandwidth
But how would the fluctuating reference voltage not impact the output value, considering that a precise DC Vref is not required?

The MDAC reference does  impact the output voltage.
The nominal output is the reference voltage vref(t) multiplied by the digital input Code/2^N in the case of a voltage output MDAC (or some scale factor different).
All DACs with a reference voltage input are multiplying DACs in a sense, but MDACs are designed to allow the reference voltage to vary over a wide range and typically are characterized for the reference voltage changing relatively quickly with respect to time.
In the case of a 4-quadrant MDAC the reference can be negative or positive with respect to ground and the code can also be positive or negative.

Thank you! Any application references where we can use AC reference voltages for MDAC's?

See DAC datasheets such as AD78x7 where they list guaranteed characteristics with AC references, in that case 100mVp-p (small signal BW), 20Vp-p (full power BW), 6V RMS (THD).
